# Gnome How do I Run a Command as root?

Tags: gnome, sudo, gnome-terminal

I'm new to Linux and just installed the Gnome on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet (or something similar). Once inside the Gnome GUI, there is a terminal prompt but typing commands does not do anything. I've searched for hours and cannot figure out how I can start running commands as root again, so I can begin installing programs.

I've tried the following: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (does not work)

```
sudo -i

gnome-terminal

gksu gnome-terminal

sudo -H gnome-terminal
```

the above commands do not print out any text, just do not run.

Comment: The question is not the same and does not contain the answer I am looking for.

Comment: all you have to do is type sudo before you type your command.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and use the terminal should be correct.

Comment: Why? I mean fair enough that you make this claim, but it's not clear why this is supposedly correct or more correct than any other method (incl. Alt+F2).

Answer (score -2):

In GUI you you should use:

```
gksu command
```

or

```
gksudo command
```

But note, this is only for graphical applications to run them from superuser.
For CLI applications just:

```
sudo command
```

Comment: None of these work. Originally the prompt said root@name:~#, I then typed gnome-session and the root@name: part went away, now when I type a command and press enter it just goes to a new line.

Comment: What exact command do you typing ?